# AENUM creating class bodies dynamically causes pylint warning

Tags: enums, python-3.6

I cannot explain why I get a `pylint "<class 'AttributeError'>: 'For' object has no attribute 'targets'"` warning when I create enum entries dynamically.

I cannot see any reason for the the warning in my code.

```
from aenum import IntEnum

class Commands(IntEnum):
    _ignore_ = 'Commands index'
    _init_ = 'value string'

    BEL = 0x07, 'Bell'
    Commands = vars()
    for index in range(4):
        Commands[f'DC{index + 1}'] = 0x11 + index, f'Device Control {index + 1}'

for command in Commands:
    print(f"0x{command.value:02X} is {command.string}")
```

The code works fine but I do NOT expect a warning!

Answer (score 0):

The code is OK the bug was within the toolchain:
https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2719